# How to modify a pandas dataframe slice by slice?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Basically I want to do work with a pandas dataframe one slice at a time and I want the changes to that slice be reflected in the original dataframe. As an example, in the following code I take a slice of `df` which is `sub_df` and then a slice of that which is `sub_sub_df`. Now I want to make changes to `sub_sub_df` and I want those changes to be reflected back in `df`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = np.random.choice([0,1,2,3,4,5], size=100)
df['b'] = np.random.choice([-1,+1], size=100)
df['out'] = np.zeros(shape=(100,))

for i in [0,3,4]:
    sub_df = df[df.a == i]
    for j in [-1,+1]:
        sub_sub_df = sub_df[sub_df.b == j]
        sub_sub_df.out = np.random.normal()
df.head()
```

This shows that the 'c' column of df is still zeros and the changes that I did to `sub_sub_df` have not propagated back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated code below should work i guess

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = np.random.choice([0,1,2,3,4,5], size=100)
df['b'] = np.random.choice([-1,+1], size=100)
df['out'] = np.zeros(shape=(100,))

for i in [0,3,4]:
    sub_df = df[df.a == i]
    for j in [-1,+1]:
        sub_sub_df = sub_df[sub_df.b == j]
        index_ = sub_sub_df.index
        df.loc[index_, 'out'] = np.random.normal()
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that tracks the minimal index at each step:

```python
for i in [0,3,4]:
    sub_idx = df.index[df.a == i]
    for j in [-1,+1]:
        sub_sub_idx = sub_idx[df.loc[sub_idx, 'b'] == j]
        df.loc[sub_sub_idx, 'out'] = np.random.normal()
```